# Can I use IN and findBy together in Groovy and Grails?

Tags: list, grails, groovy, findby

I've been trying to figure out how to do something like

```
SELECT * FROM domain WHERE config_id IN (1, 2, 3)
```

when using the nice `findBy` technique of Grails. Haven't really figured out how yet though, is it even possible? I was hoping for something like

```
Domain.findByConfigIn(configList)
```

but that doesn't work. Anyone knows how to do this, or even if it's possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming your domain class has a field named **configId**, the following should do what you want:

```
Domain.findAllByConfigIdInList(configList)
```